# Help for this equation

Tags: trigonometry, fractions, substitution

Can anyone show me how to solve  this trignometric equation :

> $$\sin(2θ)-\cos(2θ)=\frac 1 2$$

Comment: Can you kindly show us what you have tried so that we can help you better? :)

Comment: You can get pretty far by squaring both sides here

Comment: Please include context about whence this problem came and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use

$$\cos2\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

$$\sin2\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

where

$$t=\tan \theta$$

and solve for t, that is

$$t^2+4t-3=0$$

Comment: Alternatively clear fractions and write in terms of $\theta$ rather than $2\theta$ with $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta =1$, use $s=\sin \theta, c=\cos \theta, t=\frac sc=\tan \theta$ to obtain:$$4sc-2c^2+2s^2=s^2+c^2$$

So that $$t^2+4t-3=0$$

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes indeed it can be obtained also by the other basic identities. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It's $$\sin\left(2\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$$ and the rest is smooth:
$$2\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}=(-1)^n\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)+\pi n,$$ where $n$ is integer or
$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{8}+ (-1)^n\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)+\frac{\pi n}{2}.$$

Comment: I got till here...what should  I do after that

Comment: @GENESECT  I added something. See now.

Answer (score -1):

use that $$\sin(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$